# Does SSIS consider wild card characters in CSV input?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a SQL table that stores filename and ssis package name. Whenever the file gets dropped to a directory, the corresponding ssis package gets triggered referring the mapping table.

If I store the file name as say, `a*.csv` in database and the corresponding ssis package as `sample-ssis.dtsx`, Will I be able to trigger the same package for any csv file starting with "a"? Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can read the file name into a variable and use a script task to loop through your mapping table and see if any of the filename-with-wildcard entries in the mapping table match the file name in the variable.